# In Objective-C, fabsf() has the wrong result type

Tags: objective-c

If in the Xcode's debug console I type

```
(lldb) p (float)fabsf(-5.0f)
(float) $22 = 0
(lldb) p (double)fabsf(-5.0f)
(double) $23 = 5
```

where the **first result** casting to float (without casting, the `p` command can't recognize the `fabsf` return type) ***is wrong no matter the parameter***.

But in the library headers the return type of `fabs` is clearly a float. Can somebody explain me this?

> ios9.2: math.h

```
...
extern float fabsf(float);
extern double fabs(double);
extern long double fabsl(long double);
...
```

Is there some lldb mechanism or issue which I am not aware of, or really a language implementation issue (guess not...)?

Comment: I could not reproduce your results, running against the simulator.

Comment: I indeed reproduced on iPhone 6s, Xcode 7.2. Waiting for answer))

Comment: Reproducible in lldb under OS X directly. Same happens with other `float` returning functions (e.g. `fmaxf`) and casts. I'd suggest a bug and you should report to Apple (bugreport.apple.com)

Comment: I filled a ticket on apple bugtracker, but they are slower than with their app review process. That is a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was pretty sure a bug of lldb console in Xcode 7, and [a ticket](https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5675939153313792) was created for it.

The issue is not present any more in Xcode 8.0.